# For loop inside while loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that needs to be called inside a loop is a condition is true. I have to call the function an x amount of times. I tried putting the for loop inside the while loop, but then the function kept getting called over and over again. I made an example:

```
gamescene = 0
x = 0

def function():
    global x
    x = x + 1
    print(x)

while True:
    if gamescene == 0:
        for y in range(5):
            function()
```

I want the function to only print out x times, but because it's in a loop, it prints forever and I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: raise the gamescore somehow or use a break to leave the while. also: read [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and get yourself something to debug your program.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Alex You want to print out X times but you don't use X in you loop as a counter. WHY?

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to check the value of `x`:

```
def function():
    global x
    x = x + 1
    if x <= 5: print(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem lies within

```
while True
```

This continuously repeats the code under it, so it checks after 5 times if the gamescene is 0 again, repeat is another 5 times etc.

You should change the gamescene to be nonzero within the while loop, or remove the while loop.